# PHP, обработка syntax error

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

Пишу небольшой ErroeHandler для обработки ошибок PHР, но не могу разобраться с синтаксическими ошибками, к примеру, если пропущена точка с запятой, либо стоит некорректный символ.

Какие есть способы искусственно обработать синтаксические ошибки PHP?

Comment: Вряд ли есть, потому что анализатор не может знать, что конкретно имел в виду разработчик и поэтому делать за него работу не имеет смысла, потому что смысл может быть поменян совсем на противоположный

Comment: "либо стоит некорректный символ." --- а что под этим подразумевается? можно пример(ы)?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский к примеру точка, либо любой другой символ, который вызовет syntax error.

Comment: а как исправлять, например, такую синтаксическую ошибку: ``$n = 0.233.2.65`` ?

Comment: Интерпретатор [не позволяет](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) пользователю обрабатывать ошибки [синтаксиса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900208/php-custom-error-handler-handling-parse-fatal-errors) - (Ошибки следующих типов не могут быть обработаны пользователем: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING независимо от того, где они были сгенерированы)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Очень жаль, спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: **Да так же, как и любые другие!** Никакой разницы. Какая **конкретно** проблема-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос хороший, но не до конца продуман.

Синтаксические ошибки обрабатываются точно так же как и любые другие.

*Разумеется*, обработчик не сработает, если если ошибка допущена до того, как он успел загрузиться: например, в скрипте, который его подключает, или если ошибка в самом обработчике. Но это всё очевидные кейсы, с которыми можно смириться.

Но если ошибка синтаксиса произошла в любом другом файле, после того как обработчик уже загрузился, то она прекрасно обработается.

Представим, что у нас есть файл-загрузчик приложения (который практически никогда не меняется), который сначала подключает системные файлы (включая обработчик ошибок), а потом инклюдит файлы с бизнес-логикой. При такой схеме все ошибки в файлах с бизнес-лоикой будут прекрасно ловиться:

```
<?php

require 'error_handler.php';
require 'controller.php';
```

ошибка синтаксиса в controller.php будет поймана так же, как и любая другая. То есть в 99.99% файлов проекта ошибки синтасиса будут ловиться.

Comment: В этом и проблема, вместо кастомного ErrorHandler я получаю сообщение стандартного обработчика ошибок **PHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ".", expecting end of file**. Возможно вы могли бы сделать пример для меня, чтобы я понял как это возможно реализовать у себя.

Comment: я не знаю, как сделать пример ещё проще. Вы можете сделать файл из двух строчек, `<?php set_exception_handler(function() {echo "Exception handler called\n";} ); include 'error.php';` и сделать в error.php ошибку синтаксиса?

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное время и помощь. Чуть выше в комментариях я указал ссылку на свой ErrorHandler на github.
Я сделал всё так как вы сказали и оно почему-то работает, после всего этого я абсолютно перестал понимать почему мой ErrorHandler не работает с ошибками E_PARSER (syntax error). Оказалось всё куда проще, я пытался вызвать ошибку в том же файле, в котором и подключен сам класс ErrorHandler. Когда я попытался вызвать ошибку E_PARSE в другом файле для своего ErrorHandler он обработал её корректно. Ещё раз спасибо за уделенное время и ответ! :)

Comment: я бы еще порекомендовал убрать собачки из кода, а то совсем некрасиво получается. и для отдачи заголовка есть очень удобная функция http_response_code(500);

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли есть, потому что анализатор не может знать, что конкретно имел в виду разработчик и поэтому делать за него работу не имеет смысла, потому что смысл может быть поменян совсем на противоположный

Примеры банальные.

```
function test {
    if () {
        ...
        
        if (...) {
            тут код В БЛОК IF
    
        тут код ВНЕ IF
        ещё код ВНЕ IF
    }
}
```

Забыта закрывающая скобка у второго `if`. Где анализатор должен автоматически поставить скобку? Как он должен понять, что после первой строчки, а не после последней?

Или вот такая ошибка:

```
echo $wrong[key];
// Use of undefined constant key
```

Что должен сделать анализатор? Обернуть в кавычки? А если программист забыл там доллар и хотел написать

```
echo $wrong[$key];
```

Еще один пример, чисто виртуальный, хоть и глуповат

```
$test= 1;
echo $test  '1';
```

Что здесь должно быть? Может быть `.` (конкатенация), а может быть `+` (сложение). И что надо выбрать анализатору?

---

И таких примеров тысячи. Анализатор просто не знает что вы хотели, т.к. на одну синтаксическую ошибку найдётся тысячи вариантов для исправления (сравнимо комбинациям в шахматах, пойти можно куда угодно, но вот тактику, которую нужно соблюсти, знаете только вы). Так что отбросьте мысли о магическом инструменте, т.к. инструмент, читающий мысли ещё не изобрели %)

Comment: Простите конечно! Но где я написал, что код должен сам себя писать / исправлять? В комментариях к вопросу пользователь @DanielProtopopov дал верный ответ. Вы вероятно ошиблись темой и хотели дать ответ в другой теме? Если это не так, то пожалуйста, прочтите мой вопрос ещё раз.

Comment: Да, возможно не так понял) Т.к. вопрос "Какие есть способы искусственно обработать синтаксические ошибки PHP?" звучит явно двусмысленно))

Comment: Возможно вы и правы. Я пишу ErrorHandler, который показывает файл с его кодом, указывает на строку в которой допущена ошибка и выводит все необходимые данные. По сути он заменяет ошибки и Exception в PHP, в аналогии с Symfony ErrorHandler ( https://i.imgur.com/l0LOqZa.png ). Но проблема лишь в том, что синтаксические ошибки обрабатываются лишь стандартным обработчиком PHP.

Comment: @Zerxa как именно устроен ваш обработчик, что он вдруг не ловит ошибки? Вы его в том же самом файле, что ли, пишете?

Comment: @Ипатьев https://github.com/ZerxaFun/ErrorHandler